# Why does a Dockerfile condition not work?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I tried to set a build argument in docker-compose.yml in order not to remove a file for a specific service, but it does not work: file is always removed.

I have got Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM docker.io/python:3.11.4

ARG BASE_DIR=/opt/app
ARG REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK

WORKDIR ${BASE_DIR}
COPY ./pyproject.toml ./poetry.lock ./

RUN if [ $REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK==1 ]; then rm poetry.lock && echo condition_01 >condition_01.txt; else echo "poetry.lock is not removed" > condition_02.txt; fi
RUN echo "REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK: ${REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK}" >REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK_value.txt
```

I have got docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  min_django_version:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK=0
    image: min_django_version:latest
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

I run:

```bash
docker compose up -d --build
docker compose exec -it min_django_version bash
ls
```

I see:

```bash
REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK_value.txt  condition_01.txt  pyproject.toml
```

I run:

```bash
cat REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK_value.txt
```

and I see:

```bash
REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK: 0
```

I expected that poetry.lock would not be removed because REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK: 0, but it is removed. Why? How should I change the condition in order not to remove the file?

Comment: You need to expand the variables, `if [ "$REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK" == 1 ]` should work

Comment: if [ "$REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK" == 1 ] - yes, the file is not removed
but if [ "$REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK" == 0 ] - the file is not removed two.
Do you mean that if I want to skip the file, I should use the quotation marks and If I want to remove the file, I should not use them?

Comment: I missed you're not using strings... See my answer, should work now

Comment: You should _always_ use the quotation marks.

Comment: @KevinKopf   "==" is not an operator for the test command. It has to be either "=" or -eq

Comment: @xpusostomos check the gnu.org link in my answer, there's both `==` and `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) official docs:

> **arg1 OP arg2**
>
> OP is one of ‘-eq’, ‘-ne’, ‘-lt’, ‘-le’, ‘-gt’, or ‘-ge’. These arithmetic binary operators return true if arg1 is equal to, not equal to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to arg2, respectively. Arg1 and arg2 may be positive or negative integers. When used with the [[ command, Arg1 and Arg2 are evaluated as arithmetic expressions (see Shell Arithmetic).

Therefore you need to use `if [ "$REMOVE_POETRY_LOCK" -eq 1 ]`.